# How to get the image name of button in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I am new to `IOS and Objective-C`.

I set the image to the button like the following code.

```
UIButton *modeChangeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(233, 490, 60, 60)];
[modeChangeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordmode.PNG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:modeChangeButton];
```

But how to get the image name of the `button` ?

For example, I want to get the **recordmode.PNG**...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `UIImage` does not store the name of the `image` it contains. You have to store the name elsewhere by yourself in relationship to the `Button` or `image`.

Answer (score 3):

To set the image name use below code:

```
[Your_Button setAccessibilityIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]];
```

Where `imageName=@"recordmode.PNG";`

And to get the image name

```
[Your_Button accessibilityIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

First Store Your Image Name in a String  like

```
NSString * imageNameString = @"yourImageName.png";
```

and then

```
UIButton *modeChangeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(233, 490, 60, 60)];
[modeChangeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:modeChangeButton];
```

if you want your button image name simply use `imageNameString`

Answer (score 0):

Get the name of the UIImage in iOS，this is working！

example：

```
let sender = UIButton(type: .custom)
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Item_center_H"), for: .normal)

if let image = sender.image(for: .normal) {
   DDLog(image.assetName)  // Item_center_H

}
```

code：

```
@objc public extension UIImage{

    var assetName: String? {
        guard let imageAsset = imageAsset else { return nil }
        return imageAsset.value(forKey:"assetName") as? String
    }
}
```